# xlwings: terminate connection with the excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Suppose I have the following code in xlwings (Python 2.7):

```
toolWb = xw.Book(element)
sht = toolWb.sheets['Output']
sht.range('A1').value = 'Test'
```

Do you know how xlwings terminates the interaction with an Excel file?

I would like the user to be able to save and close the file without any conflict.

Is there a command to kill the connection? (leaving open the excel file as xlwings usually does)